# Create modal pop up in chrome extension appear outside of default popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am currently using HTML, JS and CSS to create a chrome extension.

Once a button has been pressed, I would like a modal pop up to appear in the bottom right hand corner of the screen.

So far, the pop up only appears inside the default pop up for the extension rather than on the actual page.

I have added the html for the modal inside a div in the "default_popup" referred to in manifest.json. Everything works apart from where it appears.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think that what you are trying to achieve is a panel, or detached panel. You can find information about that here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows

Comment: @telex-wap Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Panels are now deprecated. I don't think this will work on an extension.